# Include common code using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple HTML navbar that I do not want to recreate for every page. I know I can do this simply using PHP, but is there a simple way to do it using jQuery?

If so, is it "corrcect" to do so?

Comment: 99.999% of the time, it's **not** correct to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple to create HTML in javascript (at least if using jQuery) and insert it into every document that includes the .js file, all you have to do is something like:

```
$('<div id="mydiv"><span>Hello World</span></div>').appendTo('somelement');
```

On the other hand it's a bad idea to do this unless there is some good reason, as mixing HTML into your javascript is consider bad practice.
It will give users without JS problems, and it will create more problems for you since the elements now are inserted dynamically and events and listeners will have to be set up accordingly!

Comment: Can you effectively browse without JS anymore? Is it a real issue to deal with?

Comment: @maddogandnoriko: Yes. If nothing else, for accessibility reasons.

Comment: I've, for the most part, stopped catering to those without Javascript. Almost everyone, including mobile clients, are capable of JS. At most, I'll add a noscript informing them they need JS.

Comment: I believe it's not really an issue, as most people have JS enabled now, and creating sites for the 0.001% that doesn't is not something I'm going to consider. I sometimes use HTML in JS, but not just for the convinience of including it into several files, there has to be other reasons and I would never include something like a complete navigation or something else that would be a large part of a site with JS, that's just silly and belongs on the serverside of things?

Comment: I agree with Ulrich - in this case particularly, any screen-readers, etc which don't run Javascript aren't going to see your navigation. So you're basically reducing access to your site to the homepage for visually impaired users. I generally assume JavaScript is present, but only in situations where it won't dramatically reduce the user experience if it's not.

Comment: @ianhales: Never thought about visually impaired readers. That is a real possibility, I think. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some JavaScript code that generates your navbar - then just include the call to that script in your markup :

`<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_your_script"></script>`

If you include this script more than once the users browser will most likely cache the script and it will be loaded from cache the next time it is requested.

Essentially all you HTML is "recreated" every time the user arrives on the page.  Even when using PHP the code will be executed every time the page is loaded.

---

In the event that the user has disabled JavaScript (unlikely, but still a possibility <sup>*shudder*</sup>), you might want to implement a fall-back system that swaps your jQuery navbar to a PHP generated navbar.  For that you can use the
`<noscript>` tag.

Example [(taken from here)](http://javascript.about.com/library/bltut14.htm) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write('<b>Hello Javascript World</b>');
</script>
<noscript>
  Hello World Without Javascript
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript should be used to add functionality to existing elements. Using it to create a navigation structure is very dangerous - how will the user navigate your site if they have javascript disabled?

I would put your code in a PHP include file.